# send back to requested page after authentication in angular js ; need better approach

Tags: angularjs, authentication

I have 3 page A, B and C. A requires login;

- user click on A
- check for authentication ( whether user logged in or not)
- if user not logged in than login page appears
- after successful login , sent back to A

---

right now what I have done so far; here is my **[working plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/AcQk0Zrik1RjgXL4qLSm/)**

1. add *params* to login state and set to null in *.config* block

   ```
   $stateProvider
     .state("login", {
           url: '/login',
           controller: 'LoginController',
           data : { pageTitle : 'Home', requiresAuth: true }
           params : {'returnTo' : null }
   });
   ```
2. When user click to the authenticated page, we send user to login page with additional parameter in `$state.target`

   ```
   $transitions.onBefore(requiresAuthCriteria, redirectToLogin, {priority: 10} );

   var requiresAuthCriteria = {
   to: function (state) {
       return state.data && state.data.requiresAuth;
   }
   };
   var redirectToLogin = function($transition$, $injector) {
   var AuthService = $injector.get('AuthService');
   if (!AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
       return $state.target('login', { returnTo : $transition$.to().name });
   }
   ```

   };
3. On login controller; after successful login ,we bind parameter to `rootScope` and `.broadcast` the event

   ```
    login
        .controller('LoginController', function($rootScope, AUTH_EVENTS, AuthService, $stateParams){
        var self = this;
       self.login = function(credentials){
       AuthService.login(credentials).then(function(user){
           $rootScope.returnTo = $stateParams.returnTo;
           $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess);
       }, function (){
           $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginFailed);
       });
   };
   ```
4. On `.run` block we catch this broadcasted event and send user to the requested page via `$state.go`

   ```
         $rootScope.$on(AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess, function(event) {
            $timeout(function() { $state.go($rootScope.returnTo); });
         });
   ```

BUT I think, this is not a valid approach to do so as I also need to check authentication; I tried with `resolve` of *`.state`*

```
resolve : { returnTo : returnTo }

function returnTo ($transition$) {
    var redirectedFrom = $transition$.previous();
    // The user was redirected to the login state (via the requiresAuth hook)
    if (redirectedFrom !== null) {
        // Follow the current transition's redirect chain all the way back to the original attempted transition
        while (redirectedFrom.previous()) {
          redirectedFrom = redirectedFrom.previous();
        }
        return { state: redirectedFrom.to(), params: redirectedFrom.params("to") };
    }
    var fromState = $transition$.from();
    var fromParams = $transition$.params("from");
    console.log(fromState);
    if (fromState.name !== '') {
        return {state: fromState, params: fromParams};
    }
    // If the fromState's name is empty, then this was the initial transition. Just return them to the home state
    return { state: 'base' };
}
```

but do not understand why this is not working ; Kindly help me to fix this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the solution after a lot of surfing through various articles

now the alternative is using `resolve` attribute; remove `params` attribute and it's all code

1. on login state,  add `resolve` property and also add `onEnter` property so that user can not access */login* once logged in.

   ```
    .state("login", {
           url: '/login',
           templateUrl: './user/login.html',
           controller: 'LoginController',
           controllerAs : 'vm',
           resolve: { returnTo: returnTo },
           onEnter: function($state, AuthService){
               if(AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
                   return $state.target('base', undefined, { location: false });
               }
           }
       })
   ```
2. define `returnTo` function [copied from here](https://github.com/ui-router/sample-app/blob/master/app/login.state.js)

   ```
    function returnTo ($transition$) {
       var redirectedFrom = $transition$.previous();
       // The user was redirected to the login state (via the requiresAuth hook)
       if (redirectedFrom !== null) {
           // Follow the current transition's redirect chain all the way back to the original attempted transition
           while (redirectedFrom.previous()) {
             redirectedFrom = redirectedFrom.previous();
           }
           // return to the original attempted "to state"
           return { state: redirectedFrom.to(), params: redirectedFrom.params("to") };
       }
       // The user was not redirected to the login state; they directly activated the login state somehow.
       var fromState = $transition$.from();
       var fromParams = $transition$.params("from");
       if (fromState.name !== '') {
           return {state: fromState, params: fromParams};
       }
       // If the fromState's name is empty, then this was the initial transition. Just return them to the home state
       return { state: 'base' };
   }
   ```

*The real mystery is how does this `$transitions$` is available inside the function!!!, someone can explain than would be thankful*

3. now inject `$state` and `returnTo` ( function name as it is) in *.loginController* and after successful logged in , change the state using `state` and `params` value which was return as object from `returnTo` function

   ```
      login
      .controller('LoginController', function($rootScope, AUTH_EVENTS, AuthService, $state, returnTo){
        var self = this;
        self.login = function(credentials){            
           AuthService.login(credentials).then(function(user){
           $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess);
           AuthService.setCurrentUser(user);
           $state.go(returnTo.state, returnTo.params, {reload: true });
       }, function (){
           $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginFailed);
       });
   };
   ```

hope it helps someone